# (C++)trying to convert double to integer (explaining)

Tags: c++

saw this in an example

```
double x = 50.2
cout << (double)(int)(x);
```

this works fine , and also it works without the (double) ,
so why adding the (double) there?

Comment: How is this a "php" related issue?

Comment: Why did you tag this with Java, PHP,, and JavaScript?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner or Java, or JavaScript

Comment: You're converting from double to int and back to double. As for why: why indeed?

Comment: I think the example is trying to show you how to round down to the nearest integer? This way you end up with a double instead of an int. This can be meaningful in the right context

Comment: @VLAZ Heh, true that.

Comment: Should we add another tag as well?

Comment: C does not have `cout << `

Comment: @VLAZ  sorry for that

Comment: @BasinhetVeld the result here is integer

Comment: If the stream has std::setprecision, then casting to double would honor printing out that precision after the decimal point (which will be zeros).  Other than that, I don't see any benefit to C-style convert-casting to double.

Comment: The reason for the cast to `double` is (perhaps) to have the output formatted as floating-point. With the default settings it will look the same as the `int` value, but with other settings it won't.

Comment: @PeteBecker i see , ty for your answer  , would you mind sharing an example for using double and the result will not look like as the int ?

Comment: `std::cout << std::showpoint << (double)(int)x << '\n';`. Try it with and without the `(double)` cast.

Comment: @PeteBecker ty so much ,I appreciate who helped me here .

Comment: @SnakeEyez -- you should also look at the comment by Eljay, who said something similar to my comment before I posted mine.

Comment: didnt see his , thank u

Comment: -7 votes XD ok ty i guess , at least some ppl cared to help

Comment: @SnakeEyez Just because it (std::cout) prints an integer doesn't mean it is an integer. Your double is first converted to int, then back to double.

Comment: @BasinhetVeld yeah got the idea , ty tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to add (Double) there, why indeed. You are converting 50.2 to int wich evaluates to 50, then you are converting 50 back to double wich stays at 50 If you print it. The only reason i can think to do this is If it's inside some function with a return double value or to extract the integer part of a Double value, but it's not a good practice at all.

Comment: ok ty i understand now

Comment: Where did you saw this example? The only reason i can think to do this is If it's inside some function with a return double value

Comment: saw this in an example so i was wandering why exactly

Comment: Maybe, is showing how to extract the integer part of a Double value

Comment: I shall enfatize that this is not a good practice

Comment: in a pdf book to learn c++ ,as i just started learning c++

Comment: yeah it confused the hell out of me